# Invalidating Jews as the Suffering Servant

Tags: sources-mekorot, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, suffering

I saw [this](https://jewsforjudaism.org/knowledge/articles/isaiah-53-teaches-jesus-not-messiah/) post in which a rabbi explains why Is. 53 cannot be talking about Jesus. The essential line is

> This tells us that someone who is widely respected BEFORE the arm of the Lord is revealed – CANNOT be the servant that Isaiah was talking about.

While it is easy to say that, historically, the oppression and violence perpetrated against Jews indicates a lack of "respect," more recently, studies, [articles](https://www.usatoday.com/in-depth/news/world/inside-iran/2018/08/29/iran-jewish-population-islamic-state/886790002/) [and](https://www.pewforum.org/2017/02/15/americans-express-increasingly-warm-feelings-toward-religious-groups/) [polls](https://www.jta.org/2017/02/15/united-states/pew-jews-are-best-liked-religious-group-in-america) have reported that in a large sense, Jews are **not** despised and shunned (53:3). This is not to say that everyone likes, respects or is nice to Jews, but there is no 100% consensus on liking Jesus and the general sense is enough to invalidate him in the eyes of the author.

If that's the case, is there any discussion online or off about whether the position of the Jewish people as the servant is called into question by the recent (at least relative) warming up of people to Jews or could/should be, in the future, rethought if this trend continues around the world?

Comment: What is the question

Comment: in the final paragraph, the sentence which begins with "is there" and ends with a question mark.

Comment: Question is too wordy with many unnecessary phrases

Comment: When you ask it, you can use your writing style.

Comment: There is an Aish.com article about this BN I'll try to look it up later. Spolier alert: it reaches the conclusion that the Jewish people has suffered to the extent that a couple of decades of somewhat better treatment in certain countries does not invalidate our position

Comment: Arguably what you're looking for: https://www.aish.com/sp/ph/Isaiah_53_The_Suffering_Servant.html?mobile=yes

Comment: @JoshK I just zoomed through that article and didn't see where it discusses what you report as the conclusion. It indicates "This verse describes the Servant as universally despised and rejected." This seems only to strengthen my question.

Comment: "He was despised and rejected of men, a man of pains and accustomed to sickness. As one from whom we would hide our faces, he was despised, and we had no regard for him.

This verse describes the Servant as universally despised and rejected. This has been a historical theme for the Jewish people, as a long list of oppressors have treated the Jews as sub-human (the Nazis) or as a pariah state (the United Nations). See similar imagery in Isaiah 49:7, 60:15; Psalms 44:14; Nechemia 3:36."

Comment: Considering your choice of icon, you're clearly well aware of how diverse, omnipresent, and enduring antisemitism continues to be. (or perhaps not?)

Comment: @Loewian I'm aware of many things including the danger of the article I cite. I'm just trying to see if anyone has considered the argument which would develop naturally as a response to that article. If I, in a quick search, can find support for the idea that Jews, through the anti-semitism, are becoming respected or liked, then someone making a more substantial attempt at research can find more to support the idea that, by the same logic, Jews are not the Servant. Is it wrong to ask if anyone has wrestled with this already?

Comment: Several millennia on, this somehow isn't my greatest worry.

Comment: Israel was also "respected" and "liked" briefly by the liberal world between 1948 and 1967.

Comment: @Loewian I don't save my worries for any greatest worry, but for questions and problems. To my understanding, this article creates a logical issue. I'm curious if anyone has dealt with it. I spend time combating missionaries online and if they raise this objection to Israel as the Servant it would be useful if I had material with which to respond.

Comment: See the magistral work is the psychoanalyst Bela Grünberger "Narcissisme, Judaïsme, antisémitisme."

Answer (score 3):

Where/when religion is in vogue, Jews are and have been hated ("nobly" once called "*Judenhaas*") for rejecting Jesus (or Mohammed).  Where/when religion is passe, and "science" is the highest cause, Jews were "nobly" hated because of their "biological race" ("antisemitism").

Likewise, Jews have been (and still are) historically hated by the far right as "Communists", "N-lovers", "homosexuals"; hated by the left as "Capitalists", "religious fanatics", "Zionists", "racists".  Hatred of the Judaeans and their faith has spanned (and still spans) the globe - in the Far East, in Russia, Indonesia, Japan, the Middle East, Europe, and South America.  Likewise it spans diverse communities, such as the American "Alt Right", the American left; and the African American community (e.g. as "slave traders"). Antarctica seems the only antisemitism-*rein* continent, but I'm pretty sure if someone understood penguins, we'd quickly discover they believe Israel is the reason it's so cold down there.

Furthermore, based on, for example, today's Jerusalem Post Online, your reports of antisemitism's demise seem greatly exaggerated:

1. https://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Activists-get-violent-during-Reservists-on-Duty-at-York-University-608617
2. https://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Police-say-attack-on-76-year-old-Berlin-man-was-antisemitic-608524
3. https://www.jpost.com/Breaking-News/German-Ambassador-Pompeos-statement-does-not-change-international-law-608562
4. https://www.jpost.com/Breaking-News/Jewish-man-stabbed-in-Monsey-NY-is-in-critical-condition-Report-608438
5. https://www.jpost.com/International/Anti-Jewish-Museum-gives-award-to-anti-Israel-German-FM-608513
6. https://www.jpost.com/Opinion/Fighting-antisemitism-608486
7. https://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Antisemitism/NY-State-assemblyman-calls-to-protect-free-speech-at-Binghamton-University-608234
8. https://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Antisemitism/Labour-Partys-Zarah-Sultana-taunts-university-students-over-Israel-608099
9. https://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Antisemitism/NYU-antisemitism-investigation-ongoing-following-several-incidents-607954
10. https://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Antisemitism/Teen-arrested-and-charged-with-hate-crimes-for-egging-Jews-in-Brooklyn-607939
11. https://www.jpost.com/Diaspora/Antisemitism/GWU-students-call-for-university-to-adopt-antisemitic-acts-definition-608105

If anything, I'm still reminded of the 20th century joke about the Jew who, rather than read the ever-depressing Jewish media about antisemitic persecution and Jewish suffering, chooses to read the antisemitic media where the Jews are all wealthy and control the world.  (As far as when the time does eventually come that the Jews are no longer despised, I think the best thing to tell your confused colleagues is to pack their bags for the end is nigh.)

Comment: This reaffirms that anti-Semitism and hatred still exist but begs the question of how "universal" the hatred has to be before someone can say that the description doesn't fit.

Comment: @rosends I think this comment gets to the heart of the matter.  But it's more something you have to ask yourself as part of your commendable anti-missionary work than something we can help you with

Comment: @If I'm looking for sources who might have discussed this issue then one would think that a site like this would be somewhere to ask for sources.